# Perl: How to add additional column to each row in multi-dimensional array

Tags: perl

I have two multi-dimensional arrays: array1(@wipr) and array2(@widesc)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
  
# Initializing and defining the array
my @wipr = ( ['1111', '2221'],
              ['1112', '2222'],
              ['1113', '2223'],
              ['1115', '2225'],
              ['1113', '2224'] );
my @widesc = ( ['1111', 'Bug1'],
              ['1112', 'Feature1'],
              ['1113', 'Feature2'],
              ['1114', 'Feature2'] );
# Printing items from the array
#print Dumper(\@wipr);
#print Dumper(\@widesc);

# Using For loop
for(my $m = 0; $m <= $#wipr; $m++)
{   
   for(my $n = 0; $n <= $#widesc ; $n++)
   {  
      #print $wipr[$m][0], "\n";
      #print $widesc[$n][0];
      if ( "$wipr[$m][0]" == "$widesc[$n][0]" )
      {
          print "Matches: $wipr[$m][0] == $widesc[$n][0]";
          my $desc="$widesc[$n][1]";
          print "desc value is : $desc";
          #push(@{$wipr[$m][1][$m]},"$desc");
          #print "$wipr[$m][1][$m]";
          $wipr[$m][1][$m] = "'$desc'";
          #push (@wipr,$wipr[$m][1][$m]);
      }
      #else
      #{
        #  print "Doesn't Matches: $wipr[$m][0] == $widesc[$n][0]";
      #}
   }  
   print "\n";  
} 
print Dumper(\@wipr);
```

If the values of first column in array1(@wipr) matches to values of first column in array2(@widesc), we need to get add 2nd element of array2, into array1.
If value didn't match, it should just put a string "not found"

**Required Output should be:**

```
 my @result= ( ['1111', '2221', 'Bug1'],
                  ['1112', '2222', 'Feature1'],
                  ['1113', '2223', 'Feature2'],
                  ['1115', '2225', 'Not Found'],
                  ['1113', '2224', 'Feature2'] );
```

I got stuck at adding third column in array1. Can you help with it.

**Error:** can't use string ("2221") as an array ref while "strict refs" in use at arrays1.pl line33.

Comment: `push( @{$wipr[$m]}, $desc );` or `$wipr[$m][2] = $desc;`

Comment: I want it to be added as third column. Error I see is "can't use string ("2221") as an array ref while "strict refs" in use at arrays1.pl line33."

Comment: line 33 seems to be: `$wipr[$m][1][$m] = "'$desc'";`. `@wipr` is an array. `@wipr[$m]` is an array. `$wipr[$m][1]` is a string. `@wipr[$m][1]`  is not an array. So indexing into it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks jhnc.
This is addressed.
`# Using For loop
for(my $m = 0; $m <= $#wipr; $m++)
{   
   for(my $n = 0; $n <= $#widesc ; $n++)
   {  
      #print $wipr[$m][0], "\n";
      #print $widesc[$n][0];
      if ( "$wipr[$m][0]" == "$widesc[$n][0]" )
      {
          print "Matches: $wipr[$m][0] == $widesc[$n][0]";
          my $desc="$widesc[$n][1]";
          print "desc value is : $desc";
          #push(@{$wipr[$m][1][$m]},"$desc");
          #print "$wipr[$m][1][$m]";
          $wipr[$m][1][$m] = "'$desc'";
          #push (@wipr,$wipr[$m][1][$m]);
      }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naïve way:

```perl
my @result;
for my $wipr (@wiprs)
   my $wi1 = $wipr->[0];

   for my $widesc (@widescs)
      my $wi2 = $widesc->[0];
      if ($wi1 == $wi2) {
         push @result, [ $wi1, $wipr->@[1..$#$wipr],  $widesc->@[1..$#$widesc] ];
         last;
      }
   }
}
```

This is very slow. If there are N WIs, The inner loop is executed N*N/2 times. This means the time taken is proportional to the square of N<sup>2</sup>.

When something takes resources (e.g. time) indirectly proportional to the square of N<sup>2</sup>, we say it's O(N<sup>2</sup>).

---

The reason the above is so slow is the process taken to match up the records. What if the arrays were sorted?

```perl
@wiprs   = sort { $a->[0] <-> $b->[0] } @wiprs;
@widescs = sort { $a->[0] <-> $b->[0] } @widescs;

my $pr_i = 0;
my $desc_i = 0;

my @results;
while ($pr_i < @wiprs && $desc_i < @widescs) {
   my $wipr   = $wiprs[$pr_i];
   my $widesc = $widescs[$desc_i];

   my $wi1 = $wipr->[0];
   my $wi2 = $wipdesc->[0];

   my $cmp = $wi1 <=> $wi2;
   if ($cmp < 0) {
      ++$pr_i;
   }
   elsif ($cmp > 0) {
      ++$desc_i;
   }
   else {
      push @result, [ $wi1, $wipr->@[1..$#$wipr],  $widesc->@[1..$#$widesc] ];
      ++$pr_i;
      ++$desc_i;
   }
}
```

This is O(N log N). It's a *lot* better.

If we assume there's two arrays have all the same WIs, the above simplifies to the following:

```perl
die "Bad data\n" if @wiprs != @widescs;

@wiprs   = sort { $a->[0] <-> $b->[0] } @wiprs;
@widescs = sort { $a->[0] <-> $b->[0] } @widescs;

my $pr_i = 0;
my $desc_i = 0;

my @results;
while ($pr_i < @wiprs && $desc_i < @widescs) {
   my $wipr   = $wiprs[$pr_i];
   my $widesc = $widescs[$desc_i];

   my $wi1 = $wipr->[0];
   my $wi2 = $wipdesc->[0];

   die "Bad data\n" if $wi1 != $wi2;

   push @result, [ $wi1, $wipr->@[1..$#$wipr],  $widesc->@[1..$#$widesc] ];
   ++$pr_i;
   ++$desc_i;
}
```

Of course, if the arrays are already sorted, it simplifies to the following O(N) solution:

```perl
die "Bad data\n" if @wiprs != @widescs;

my $pr_i = 0;
my $desc_i = 0;

my @results;
while ($pr_i < @wiprs && $desc_i < @widescs) {
   my $wipr   = $wiprs[$pr_i];
   my $widesc = $widescs[$desc_i];

   my $wi1 = $wipr->[0];
   my $wi2 = $wipdesc->[0];

   die "Bad data\n" if $wi1 != $wi2;

   push @result, [ $wi1, $wipr->@[1..$#$wipr],  $widesc->@[1..$#$widesc] ];
   ++$pr_i;
   ++$desc_i;
}
```

---

Finally, we get an O(N) solution without the above assumptions by building an index first.

```perl
my %widescs_lookup;
for my $widesc (@widescs)
   my $wi = $widesc->[0];
   $widescs_lookup{$wi} = $widesc;
}

my @results;
for my $wipr (@wiprs)
   my $wi = $wipr->[0];

   my $wi_desc = $widescs_lookup{$wi}
      or next;

   push @result, [ $wi1, $wipr->@[1..$#$wipr],  $widesc->@[1..$#$widesc] ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton ikegami.
Sorry, I just updated my question. I have added another element in array1. For element ['1115', '2225'], it's first value doesn't match with second array element. But, we should have unmatched elements of array as it is, with one string added. Like
['1115', '2225', 'Not Found'].

Comment: It`s super easy to adapt any of the above solutions to that scenario.